# How can i get date as 01/Jan/2015 format by using sql

Tags: sql-server

I need date this Format 01/Jan/2015  right now i'm getting as 01/01/2015
sql Query

```
select Email,CONVERT(nvarchar,date,103) from Employee
```

Comment: You should leave formatting to the consuming application. Formatting dates as they come out the database is a challenge for things like sorting at the presentation layer. Let the presentation layer handle the formatting and this is no longer an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing you are using SQL Server 2012 or higher you can use the [`FORMAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql) function.

```
select format(getdate(), 'dd/MMM/yyyy')
```

or in your example given

```
select Email,format(date, 'dd/MMM/yyyy') from Employee
```

Answer (score 2):

Try: `REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(11), YourDate, 113),' ','/')`

You can find a full list of all the `CONVERT` style codes on [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql). You can easily combine these with other functions (such as `REPLACE`) to get other formats.

Comment: thank you but i need format like 01/Jan/2015 R8 nw its giveing as 01 Jan 2015

Comment: @MdGhousemohi If you have `01 Jan 2018` as the result, you aren't using the SQL I provided. Notice the use of **`REPLACE`**.